# NPM Start doesn't work, and I run into similar errors each time

Tags: npm, create-react-app, nvm

This is what it shows on my Windows 11 terminal:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\mmjun>npm version
{ npm: '5.3.0',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  cldr: '31.0.1',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  icu: '59.1',
  modules: '57',
  node: '8.3.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2l',
  tz: '2017b',
  unicode: '9.0',
  uv: '1.13.1',
  v8: '6.0.286.52',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }

C:\Users\mmjun>nvm version
1.1.9
```

And when I tried to open my website project on VS Code using Npm Start, I kept getting these errors:

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users\mmjun\OneDrive\Desktop\bb-website\bb-website> npm start

> website-v2@0.1.0 start C:\Users\mmjun\OneDrive\Desktop\bb-website\bb-website
> react-scripts start

C:\Users\mmjun\OneDrive\Desktop\bb-website\bb-website\node_modules\webpack\lib\ChunkGraph.js:43
const ZERO_BIG_INT = BigInt(0);
                     ^

ReferenceError: BigInt is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mmjun\OneDrive\Desktop\bb-website\bb-website\node_modules\webpack\lib\ChunkGraph.js:43:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
npm ERR! website-v2@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the website-v2@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mmjun\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-12T18_34_33_857Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\mmjun\OneDrive\Desktop\bb-website\bb-website>
```

I already read through Stack Overflow for similar issues, but I just don't seem to be able to understand the possible solutions very well. Can anyone help me breakdown the steps of what I could try to do to fix this issue and run my project?

Comment: Try updating node to LTS, which is 16. You're currently on 8.

Comment: Your node version is way out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update NodeJs. **Your version (v8) is way out of date.**

You can do that with Node Version Manager (nvm).

1. First, run this to update nvm.

```bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Then, restart PowerShell.

2. Then install NodeJS LTS

```bash
nvm install node
```

will install NodeJs v16

3. Restart PowerShell again, then run these two commands.

```bash
npm install
npm start
```

I hope this works

Comment: Hello! I tried the first step with curl, but this error came up: C:\Users\mmjun>curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What would you suggest from here? I'm using Windows 11.

Comment: Haha I forgot you were on Windows. nvm doesn't work on windows, do you have another fork / version of nvm ?

Comment: @meems just forget about updating nvm for now, just do step 2 and 3